# kobuki raw encoders ticks reset

Tags: ros, encoder, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am reading raw encoders ticks values and generating the odometry using my own code, but I need to reset the encoders ticks every new run of my code. Is there a way to reset the encoders ticks without turning OFF the robot ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258437/kobuki-raw-encoders-ticks-reset/) by [AbdRenawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28149/abdrenawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When we publish an empty message to the /mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry topic when the kobuki_node is active, we can rest the odometry.

$  rostopic pub -1 /mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry std_msgs/Empty

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [H.Ruthrash](https://answers.ros.org/users/27005/h.ruthrash/) with karma: 16 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbdRenawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28149/abdrenawi/) on 2017-08-06**:
Unfortunately it doesn't. The idea is to compare my odometery with the available one, which requires resetting the encoders themselves, since in every run my odometery code includes the initial values of the Encoders.